# displaying sub menus on tab bars in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, tabbar

Is it possible to display a sub menu on a tab bar in iphone apps. I mean when a user clicks on a tab, instead of displaying a new view, displays a new set of buttons on the top of the tab.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do it without displaying a new view but that view does not have to fill the screen.  If you create a custom UIView subclass that positions itself under the button pressed, you can get the behavior you want.